# What type of user is required to connect to Basic secured elasticsearch 7.8.x from Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

Could you please help in understanding the type of role that is required for an elastic user to connect to elasticsearch from a Spring boot application. We have been using user with superuser role but due to security concerns, we are analysing changing the same. I could not find any relevant document for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to find out anything on this?

Comment: No. Ultimately we create custom permissions and assigned user with custom permissions instead of superuser